# Append to current line if previous line pattern matches

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I'm looking for `awk/sed` command to append character to current line if the previous line has a pattern?

Example:

```
SELECT customer from Cust_tab WHERE forename = "XXX"                        
sname = "YYY"
postcode="ZZ ZZZ"
```

Expected:

---

```
SELECT customer from Cust_tab WHERE forename = "XXX"   
AND sname = "YYY"                      
AND postcode="ZZ ZZZ"
```

I want to add `AND` to beginning of line if previous/first line has `=`. Tried doing

```
sed 's/WHERE.*/& AND/g'
```

but this adds to end of line and not beginning and unable to repeat it for 3rd line in file

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Post your full efforts with commands used to your question

Comment: If you want to match when the previous line contains `=`, why are you trying to match the string `WHERE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Following code may help you which will set a flag when a line is having string `SELECT` and till a empty line comes it will keep adding `AND` string to all lines.

```
awk '/^SELECT.*=/{print;flag=1;next} !NF{flag=""} flag{print "AND ",$0}' Input_file
```

---

Your question is not that clear but based on your statements and shown samples could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk '/=/{print;getline;print "AND " $0}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work for subsequent line:                                     
SELECT customer from Cust_tab WHERE forename = "XXX"                     
AND sname = "YYY"   
postcode="ZZ ZZZ"     
AND postcode="ZZ ZZZ"

Comment: @Dev, please check my EDIT code and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: I get something like this.   SELECT customer from Cust_tab     WHERE forename = "XXX"    AND sname = "YYY"     postcode="ZZ ZZZ" AND postcode="ZZ ZZZ" AND

Comment: @Dev, to be honest I am not able to understand it, please be clear in your question and if possible report the samples again too.

Answer (score 2):

with `awk`

```
$ awk 'e{$0="AND " $0; e=0}1; /=/{e=1}' file
```

Comment: Works Thanks @karakfa